# code signing with multiple entitlements plist files for iOS app

Tags: code-signing-entitlements

Is it possible to code sign an iOS application with multiple entitlements files from command line tools.

or can we have any command line tool so that we can append entries to an existing entitlements

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called PlistBuddy.

Using this we can merge two plist files, we have to write our own custom logic on how to merge it.